# SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:

Tags: sql-server, spring-batch, jdbctemplate, spring-retry, dbcp

We are in the process of moving to Azure SQL Server from Oracle DB for our Spring Batch application that runs for few hours with **50** Threads.

Below is my JDBC Configuration

```
MSSQL_DRIVERCLASSNAME: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
MSSQL_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:sqlserver://databaseFQDN:1433;databaseName=databaseName;trustServerCertificate=true"
```

I am getting the following error intermittently

```
[144] ERROR : 03.10.2022:0454 (54.161) [[]main] AbstractJob: Encountered fatal error executing job org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:141) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281) [irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120) [irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49) [irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114) [irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349) [irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574) [irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?] Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=multithreadedItemSkuProcessing.7 at state=multithreadedItemSkuProcessing.7.applyItem8 with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:91) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_292] Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:288) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:493) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:264) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getLastStepExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:106) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:91) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_292] Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:1090) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:3195) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.rollback(DelegatingConnection.java:368) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.rollback(DelegatingConnection.java:368) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.rollback(PoolingDataSource.java:323) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:285) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:493) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:264) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getLastStepExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:106) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:91) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) ~[irol-bat-applybatch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
```

or

```
ERROR : 02.11.2022:1221 (34.455) [[]SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5] AbstractStep: Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
        .....
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:93) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:105) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:93) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:301) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:192) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:91) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) [spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_265]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_265]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call itemmaintenance(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:103) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:221) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:401) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2924) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2913) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6425) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:6368) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.ensurePayload(IOBuffer.java:6346) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readBytes(IOBuffer.java:6647) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readUnicodeString(IOBuffer.java:6601) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.StreamColumns.setFromTDS(StreamColumns.java:213) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$1CursorInitializer.onColMetaData(SQLServerResultSet.java:276) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:109) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.<init>(SQLServerResultSet.java:385) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1634) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:594) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:505) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[spring-batch-jobs-2.2.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:205)
```

I am using the below MSSQL dependency

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note**:
I am running my Spring batch on AZURE KUBERNETES and it's in the same VNET as the Azure Sql database. Technically both are in the same network and network should not be the cause

Should I try: [https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/879#:~:text=We%20fixed%20this,up%20for%20free](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/879#:%7E:text=We%20fixed%20this,up%20for%20free)?

**Update (03-11-2022):** Tried the following retry setting but it didn't work. what am I missing?

```xml
<chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10" retry-limit="10" >
    <retryable-exception-classes>
        <include class="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException"/>
        <include class="org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException"/>
        <include class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException"/>
        <include class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException"/>
        <include class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException"/>
        <include class="org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException"/>
        <include class="org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException"/>
        <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException"/>
    </retryable-exception-classes>
</chunk>
```

Comment: Transient errors should be expected when using Azure, have you implemented spring retry logic? Also take a look here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/improve-jdbc-application-reliability-with-azure-sql-and-connection-pooling/

Comment: We are using DBCP1.x for connection pooling and Spring batch 2.1.x- can I still implement - spring retry logic? please suggest.

Comment: Is there a way to configure IdleTimeout in DBCP1.4?

Comment: You should add the tag `Oracle` and 'JDBC '.

Comment: I see `Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call itemmaintenance(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL Server returned an incomplete response`  Doesnot look like t-sql syntax but oracle pl/sql

Comment: It is an Azure SQL server query

Comment: this one is not obviously. Oracle pl/sql can be compatible with t-sql if you don't use special functions calls, but this one is not compatible in any sql server. have you parsed all your pl/sql scripts to make sure they are t-sql compatible?